# excluding null value whilst declaring variable as var

Tags: c#

I've been away from C# since version 7.0 and been dabbling in F#.

I want to write some code and (like F#) try to exclude null, so I'm interested in the nullable capabilities of C# post 8.0, but I don't understand how to use 'var' yet declare something as non nullable

```
IEnumerable<int> ys = Enumerable.Range(1,10);
ys = null; // error converting null value to non null
```

this, is clearly invalid, as I've explicitly excluded null - brilliant, this is what I want to do almost always.

but if I write this

```
var ys = Enumerable.Range(1,10);
ys = null;
```

this IS allowed.
(I was sort of expecting var? to allow nullable and var to not)

how do i use var (i.e. allow type inference) but disallow null values?

Comment: Have you looked at [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types) or does this not suit your purpose?

Comment: IEnumerable<int>? ys
Just ad ? Mark

Comment: You just can't - https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3591

Comment: Got you @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - yes i saw that....but wondered if there was a way around it, so there is no way to declare a variable with a non nullable inferred value as non nullable variable without declaring its full type?....I suspected that, but was amazed (thus the question)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a newer version of C#, put the following at the top of your code:

```
#nullable enable
```

This will cause you to get warnings when something could be null that shouldn't be. However, it is a warning and not an error.

Also, if you are that concerned about the types, you may want to avoid using `var` and explicitly write the type you want. This will give you the most control.

Comment: the question is really can i make var be interpreted as non nullable (without writing the full type)

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd: By assigning it a non-nullable value. But you don't get to fine tune the exact type using `var`. That's why my answer recommended against it.

Comment: yep thanks - my surprise is that there is no way to have a non nullable inferred type.